# Create unlimited, nested list in PHP

Tags: php

I know, the headline is not very specific, but I dont't know how to title it.

I want to create a list from 1 to 10. All those numbers should be clickable and open a sublist. Again with the numbers from 1-10. Like this:

- 1
- 2

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3

and so on...
Here is some code, I've got:

```
<?php
$num = $_GET['zahl'];
$zahlen = array();
while($num != 0){
  $part = $num % 10;
  array_push($zahlen, $part);
  $num = floor($num/10);
}
foreach ($zahlen as $key => $value) {
$runs = $value + 1;
for ($i=1; $i < $runs ; $i++) {
  if ($i == 1) {
    echo $ulon . "\n";
  }
  echo $lion . "\n";
  echo $a . "ordner.php?zahl=" . $i . $amiddle . $i . $aoff . "\n";
  echo $lioff . "\n";
}
for ($i=1; $i < 11 ; $i++) {
  if ($i == 1) {
    echo $ulon;
  }
  echo $lion . "\n";
  echo $a . "ordner.php?zahl=" . $zahlen[0] . $i . $amiddle . $i . $aoff;
  echo $lioff . "\n";
}
echo $uloff;
echo "\n" . "</body>";
?>
```

Comment: Do you want all sublists to also be able to open a sublist containing 10 items, ad nauseam, never ending? If so, you will need to do this some other way than pure PHP, because unless you end the loop somwhere, it will time out / break the browser.

Comment: How deep does it have to go? You can always look into recursion.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Yes. It should be unlimited. I dont't think it'll break the browser. Because nobody would open so many sublists.

Comment: @NiekvanderMaaden Thanks! I'll take a look at recursion!

Comment: Unlimited ends up in php timing out. It has to end somewhere. As with recursion you can create your function to go (n) levels deep.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they open them or not - PHP is executed on the server, when the page is loaded - if you never end the loops, it will just continue and continue and continue... you get the point? Actually, the page will probably not be very usable at all.

Comment: Okay. I've understood. But is there another solution like reloading and open another sublist?

Comment: @daniel.971 Do it with Javascript when the user click <_<

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie <br> rekursion was the right word. Thanks for your comments. I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wish to achieve should be fairly straigtforward with Javascript rather than PHP - the following uses PHP only to generate the initial list and subsequent sub-lists are generated using javascript.

```
<?php
    echo "<ul id='infinite-menu'>";
    for( $i=1; $i < 11; $i++ ){
        echo "<li>$i</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
?>


<script>

    var children=10;

    function newnodes(e){
        if( e.target.childNodes.length==1 ){
            var ul=document.createElement('ul');
            e.target.appendChild(ul);

            for( i=1; i < children+1; i++ ){
                var li=document.createElement('li');
                li.innerHTML=i;
                ul.appendChild( li );
            }
        }
    }
    var col=document.querySelectorAll('ul#infinite-menu li');
    if( col )for( n in col )if( col[n].nodeType==1){
        col[n].addEventListener('click',newnodes,false);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution based on php. Thanks for your comments!

```
<body>
<?php

$open = isset($_GET["open"]) ? $_GET["open"] : "";
$openArr = explode(",",$open);

function liste($openArr, $link) {
  $firstValue = array_shift($openArr);
  echo "<ul>";
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<a href='rekursion.php?open=".$link.$i."'>$i</a>";
    if (isset($firstValue) && $firstValue == $i) {
      liste($openArr, $link.$i.",");
    }
    echo "</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
liste($openArr,"");

?>
</body>
```